# Validar jQuery, envio de datos con submitHandler con sweet alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, servlets, jquery-validate

el [sweet alert](http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/) no se me dispara. Quizá es por el evento. Si comentamos los *sweet alert* y descomentamos un *alert* normal sí me dice el mensaje.

En mi index, me logueo, mando datos a un servlet, recupero la respuesta del sevlet y, si sus credenciales son correctas, le mando 1 y redirecciono a menú,..., sino, pues credenciales incorrectas.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#FRM_Login").validate({
        rules : {
            usuario : {
                required : true,
                minlength : 5,
                maxlength : 25
            },
            pass : {
                required : true,
                minlength : 8,
                maxlength : 12
            }
        },
        messages : {
            usuario : {
                required : "El campo usuario es obligatorio",
                minlength : "El usuario debe contener al menos 5 caracteres",
                maxlength : "El usuario debe contener no mas de 25 caracteres"
            },
            pass : {
                required : "El campo password es obligatorio",
                minlength : "La contraseña debe contener al menos 8 caracteres",
                maxlength : "La contraseña debe contener no mas de 12 caracteres"
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function (form){
            var data = $("#FRM_Login").serialize();
            $.post("Login", data, function (respuesta, estado, jqXHR){
                if(respuesta === '1'){
                    $("#BTN_Login").onclick = function(){
                        swal({
                            title: "Credenciales Correctas",
                            text: "Redireccionando...",
                            type: "success",
                            timer: 1000,
                            showConfirmButton: false
                        });
                    };
                    //alert("Credenciales Correctas");
                    var delay = 2000;
                    setTimeout(function(){ window.location = "Menu.jsp"; }, delay);
                }else{
                    $(document).ready(function(){ 
                        swal("Oops...", "Credenciales Incorrectas!", "error");
                    };
                    //alert("Credenciales Incorrectas");
                }
                $("#usuario").val("");
                $("#pass").val("");
            });
        }
    }); });
```

Comment: ¿Se muestra algún mensaje en la consola de JS?

Comment: EL parámetro "form" dentro de la función no es necesario...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No veo la necesidad del `.onclick` cuando `respuesta === 1` (ya fueron enviados los datos y solo vas a redireccionar) y cuando esta condición es falsa, normalmente `$(document).ready` no funciona en solicitudes ajax:

```
        submitHandler: function (form){
        var data = $("#FRM_Login").serialize();
        $.post("Login", data, function (respuesta, estado, jqXHR){
            if(respuesta === '1'){

                    swal({
                        title: "Credenciales Correctas",
                        text: "Redireccionando...",
                        type: "success",
                        timer: 1000,
                        showConfirmButton: false
                    });

                var delay = 2000;
                setTimeout(function(){ window.location = "Menu.jsp"; }, delay);
            }else{

                    swal("Oops...", "Credenciales Incorrectas!", "error");

            }
            $("#usuario").val("");
            $("#pass").val("");
        });
```

Comment: muchas gracias amigo me estaba matando porque me saliera esa parte de codigo no se me habia ocurrido mandarlo de un solo y como en ejemplos de aplicacion solo habia visto que mediante eventos se mandaba segun el id